# How to find duplicated rows happening in a short period within a predefined time frame in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as the following

```
number         Timestamp  
123456         17-09-2015 11:06 
455677         17-09-2015 11:09
123456         17-09-2015 11:10  
453377         17-09-2015 11:20
123456         17-09-2015 11:35
123456         17-09-2015 11:42
```

The result should be as follows:

```
123456         17-09-2015 11:06
123456         17-09-2015 11:10
```

Every hour, say from 11:00 to 12:00, I search for numbers which appear duplicate within 5 minutes. I only know some very basic sql commands. I have tried to get duplicate rows within an hour.

select t.number, group_concat(time) from my_table t where t.time>=now()-Interval 1 hour and t.time <=now() group by t.number having count(*)>1;
But finding duplicate records within 5 minutes in each 5 hours seems too complicated for me. What sql statements can do this this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post expected output as well

Comment: it's a fair question of what have you tried. But it is a bit of a medium toughness (*at least*) solution that early on sql guys won't be able to show much. So out of fairness, imo, an OP response of "I don't know how to start" seems reasonable

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will revise my question.

Comment: I have written a sql that find duplicate rows within an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following query will give you list of repetitive `number` for every 5 min  interval:

```
select number,group_concat(date_time)
from
t1
group by floor(unix_timestamp(date_time)/(5 * 60)),number having count(*)>1;
```

Verify the result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ea0/1

> ```
> Group 1: 00:00:00 to 00:04:59
> Group 2: 00:05:00 to 00:09:59
> and so on..for equal duration of 5 minutes each
> ```